# What are OOP software design patterns for managing identical React.js class hierarchies?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, oop, design-patterns

I am making a change to my React project that will result in a lot of similar classes, arranged in **identical class hierarchies**. I'm wondering what alternative organization I could use for my code.

The product currently shows a screen that is displayed on a storefront terminal, that both the store clerk and customer will interact with (reading a contract together, collecting signatures from both parties, etc.) **The incoming change is to allow a two-monitor setup**, where the clerk's monitor will control the workflow and the customer's monitor will follow along and ask for input when necessary. Single-monitor mode will still be supported.

The code currently has a main contract signing window, with visual components like the document viewer, the signature capture panel, a panel with contract details, etc. I imagine that when the two-monitor feature is completed, I will have **three nearly-identical class hierarchies** (or perhaps more accurately, identical object compositions). Components with the same suffix share a purpose and look nearly identical, but have different behaviour.

```
# Proposed object compositions
MainWindow has a DocumentViewer, and a SignaturePanel, and a DetailsPanel  
ClerkWindow has a ClerkDocumentViewer, and a ClerkSignaturePanel, and a ClerkDetailsPanel  
CustomerWindow has a CustomerDocumentViewer, and a CustomerSignaturePanel, and a CustomerDetailsPanel
```

I'm worried about the complexity growth of this pattern. When more components get added to the product, we'll need to implement three versions of each component; and although less likely, if we add another "mode", we might  have to implement a new version of every existing component.

Additionally, the `Main` components and the `Clerk` components are very similar, because they have lots of controls for the user to interact with; but the "Customer" components have much less interaction. I'm not sure how to effectively share code between two of the three components. Part of the reason it seems difficult to organize correctly is because these are Typescript React components that must have typed state and props. If I were to have the different DocumentViewer components (for example) all inherit from a common superclass, I would either inherit unused state/props in the Customer components, or I would have duplicate code managing the common state/props of Main and Clerk components.

I've considered having a single DocumentViewer (etc) class with a `mode` property that controls how the component acts on different monitor setups, but the components will end up filled with switch statements, which indicates that I want some sort of polymorphism like described above.

What design patterns exist to manage these parallel class hierarchies? Are these patterns compatible with React-style state/prop management? Are there some sort of mix-in/module features of React/Typescript to allow well-organized sharing of state/props to a subset of sibling classes?

Comment: You may want to check the [help center](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/help) of [softwareengineering.se] to see if you can make this question on topic there. This question is a bit too far into the design stage for Stack Overflow.

Comment: @HereticMonkey is it possible to migrate the post over there?

Comment: I don't have an account there, and am not sure of its topicality, so I hesitate to flag the question myself. If you are more sure, you can flag your question as "In need of moderator attention" and ask for the question to be migrated; be as specific as you can, and explain why you think it should be migrated. Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned, this is kind of an off topic question, as it relates to architecture style more than exact solutions or fixing code issues, and I'm bit on the fence wether to answer it or not.

However, it's still related to a specific technology and ecosystem and therefore might be too narrow for smaller communities. With that in mind I'll list a couple of things you can look into to explore and narrow down exact issues.

---

#### Extracting all shared code into "dumb" components

The "dumb" component is NOT an exact reference to presentational components in [some old React blogs](https://medium.com/@dan_abramov/smart-and-dumb-components-7ca2f9a7c7d0) on the topic, but follows a similar idea. In this case they are dumb about the specific type you pass, but know how to handle any shared logic or interaction.

This is something you've already described as a potential solution but you are worried about having a bunch of switch-case statements inside those components. The ways you avoid those conditional statements are:

1. Make the data you pass to those components as similar or generic as possible. You go a long way just by saying data is an object with an id and signature object.
2. All handlers and actions specific to the data type should be passed to that component hierarchy from the top-most component that is a "wrapper"/"container" for those shared components. As a simple example imagine you have a list of items with trash icons for deletion. In the container component you would implement logic for deleting an item from the list state-wise, but the rest of the interaction such as the on click handler and a warning modal would be in the shared component hierarchy.
3. If any interactions are optional, just make those properties optional. In the example above, if deletion is optional and you don't pass the delete property, the shared component knows not to show the trash icon.
4. If you have optional interactions that have 100% shared logic (e.g. is the warning modal used or not) use boolean properties as flags. It's not ideal when you're building the components to have a lot of flags, but is a common feature of many React libraries that offer complex presentational components such as tables
5. If you have specific JSX elements or React components that need to be rendered all the way down in the hierarchy, nothing is stopping you to pass those as props. Remember, everything is an object in JavaScript. To keep the same example going, this can be the warning modal's body which can be overriden if that prop is passed.
6. Now for the **TypeScript** part. Components are just classes or functions and you can use [generic classes](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/generics.html#generic-classes) or functions the same way and even **supply that generic variable into the subcomponent state and props**. And you can be more descriptive with that generic variable and say it extends an abstract class to ensure type safety and pass more info about the shared structure to the shared components.

I'll use the example I've been abusing in the following code snippet instead of your use case because I'm not quite sure of the nature of the actual implementation of your components and I want to present a short version of the idea rather than lead you on a wrong one for your use case.

```js
// abstract class for shared data
abstract class ItemBase {
  id: number;
  signature: SignatureInterface;

  static isEqual(objA: ItemBase, objB: ItemBase) {
    return objA.id === objB.id;
  }
}
// and there is some concrete class ItemTypeA that extends ItemBase

// container component render
<List<ItemTypeA>
  list={data}
  removeAction={itemDelete}
  useDeleteModal={false}
/>

// shared list component
import * as React from 'react';

interface ListProps<TItem extends ItemBase> {
  list: TItem[];
  removeAction: (id: number) => Promise<void>;
  useDeleteModal?: boolean;
  deleteModalBody?: React.ReactNode;
}

class ListComponent<TItem extends ItemBase> extends React.Component<ListProps<TItem>> {
// implementation and sub components like row that have on click handlers etc.
// ...
```

For an example how this looks in a more complex scenario check out [`react-table@6`](https://github.com/tannerlinsley/react-table/tree/v6). Note the v6 part, the [new one](https://github.com/tannerlinsley/react-table) is a complete rewrite using hooks and can also serve as a good example for going into this but using custom hooks rather than standard container props and custom [high order components](https://reactjs.org/docs/higher-order-components.html). However, I've personally still not written enough complex hooks to give a good example or suggestion about what to keep in mind.

**Possible issues with this approach:**

- Component hierarchies can be very deep and you can have a lot of props, consider using [Context](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html) or [react-redux](https://react-redux.js.org/) to mitigate this if it becomes an issue, or even develop some of your own [high order components](https://reactjs.org/docs/higher-order-components.html) to be wrappers where needed. Make sure to keep those parts generic as well.
- There is still just too much data specific code and you end up having to use a bunch of complex wrappers and still the occasional if-else to implement basic things. If this is the issue, the this code isn't a good candidate for abstraction, it just seems similar in structure (which is normal because a lot of hierarchies are similar when you abstract them). **Extract what you can and leave the rest as is, forcing patterns and abstractions where they don't fit will cause you more headaches and time wasted than doing everything separately does.** This goes double if there is a chance of features getting introduced on only one of those screens and not the others. I've shot myself in the leg with that last one on more than one occasion.

#### Extend React Class Components

This is in practice a similar idea to the one above. However, instead of passing a bunch of props to a shared component hierarchy, you extend base React components (not abstract, `React.Component` depends on having a constructor and lifecycle instance methods) that share the shared logic that you then extend. Also, you can still use generics in this case to have type safety in those shared handlers:

```js
interface BaseProps<T extends ItemBase> {}
interface BaseState<T extends ItemBase> {}
class BaseWindow<T extends ItemBase, TProps extends BaseProps<T>, TState extends BaseState<T>> extends React.Component<TProps, TState> {}

interface MainWindowProps extends BaseProps<MainItem> {}
interface MainWindowState extends BaseState<MainItem> {}
class MainWindow extends BaseWindow<MainItem, MainWindowProps, MainWindowState> {}
```

To call any method of the parent class you just call it via `super` as you would for regular components. However keep in mind that **you'll have to implement the render for every child component individually** because each will use different components. This feeds into the fact that [**inheritance is avoided in React**](https://reactjs.org/docs/composition-vs-inheritance.html), so think very carefully if your use case calls for using inheritance.

As a side note on this one, even if this is React and TypeScript, the same rulles for any OOP designs apply here and keep [Liskov Substitution Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle) in mind when doing inheritance and generics.

#### Using the `children` Prop and Context

I've already mentioned [Context](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html) in the previous example for avoiding passing props really deep on every level, but its use is intended for something much more powerful in combination with the [`children` prop](https://reactjs.org/docs/glossary.html#propschildren).

If you've opened the [Composition vs Inheritance link](https://reactjs.org/docs/composition-vs-inheritance.html) you've seen the `children` prop in action already. It's basically a way to code "wrapper" components that you can use like div-s in render. Nodes that are "boxed" as the "inner JSX" of that component are assigned to `this.props.children`

If all your shared logic in that shared hierarchy is in the containers (e.g. List in the first example) and not in the final leafs of that component, using this method might be the best option. An example for your use case would be:

```
<SharedWindow>  // same for all objects => does not need a type variable
  <DocumentViewer<ClerkType> onSignature={this.handleSignature}> 
    {/* 
      DocumentViewer contains the Signature component that needs onSignature 
      which represents various needed handlers on that component or DocumentViewer
    */}
    <ClerkDetailsPanel/>  // specific Details component
  </DocumentViewer>
</SharedWindow>
```

**Note that this is an example without Context, and you might not even need Context.**

---

Hope some of this helps. I've tried to keep this agnostic for your specific use case and be React specific at the same time so that it can be of help to you and anyone that struggles with a similar issue in the future.

Remember, there is no *silver bullet* and there are multiple correct ways to do things. It's on you as an engineer to evaluate what suits your use case in the current scenario an foreseeable future the best :)

Comment: Thanks greatly for the insight, I'll be studying this closely when I return next week.

Answer (score 1):

### Strategy

I would approach this using by using typescript generics to create a shared `Window` component that is based on a generic type which could be either `Clerk` or `Customer`.

`Window` would use a render props pattern and take three props `DocumentViewer`, `SignaturePanel`, and `DetailsPanel` specifying the components to use for each piece of the layout.

Think about what props a `DocumentViewer<T>` would need.  Which are fixed and which depend on `T`?  For each component, write a generic interface for the props that depends on `T` (where `T` is `Clerk`, `Customer`, etc.).

The specific components such as `ClerkDocumentViewer` can still be totally separate.  What matters is that the props of `ClerkDocumentViewer` fit the signature of `DocumentViewerProps<Clerk>` so that we can pass `ClerkDocumentViewer` as a render prop to `Window<Clerk>`.  In OOP terms, `ClerkDocumentViewer` is a concretion of the interface `ComponentType<DocumentViewerProps<T>>`.  Our `Window` only knows or cares about the interface, making it flexible.

Your generic setup looks something like this:

```
export interface DocumentViewerProps<T> {
  // ...
}

export interface SignaturePanelProps<T> {
  // ...
}

export interface DetailsPanelProps<T> {
  // ...
}

export interface WindowProps<T> {
  DocumentViewer: ComponentType<DocumentViewerProps<T>>;
  SignaturePanel: ComponentType<SignaturePanelProps<T>>;
  DetailsPanel: ComponentType<DetailsPanelProps<T>>;
  // ...
}

export const Window = <T>({DocumentViewer, SignaturePanel, DetailsPanel}: WindowProps<T>) => {
  // do all shared window stuff
  
  return (
    <Screen>
       {needsSignature && (
          <SignaturePanel
             // pass down all the right props, which depend on `T`
          />
       )}
       // do the same for <DocumentViewer /> and <DetailsPanel />
    </Screen>
  )
}
```

### Related Example

This is all very vague as I don't know the details of your code.  I want to share something I built using this pattern so that you can see it in action.

The app that I was working on basically has a bunch of different screens that all show a chart, graph, table, or some sort of data.  Up top I always had some controls, buttons, inputs, dropdowns, etc., that would impact the display of the data.  I realized that I was repeating myself, and came up with a generic schema for each screen.

Each screen becomes a `Tool<Settings>`.  My generic `Settings` is an object with all of the adjustable settings for the specific tool, which can be anything because it's generic.

Each `Tool` needs two components: one to render the controls and one to render the contents. When we are coming up with the props signature, remember that the render component does not need to *use* every prop, we are just describing what it *receives*.  `RenderControls` gets the current settings and a callback to update them.  `RenderContents` gets the current settings as individual props and also gets its size.  Since we are handling the state updates inside of the `Tool`, we also need to pass in the initial value for the settings.

```
export interface Props<Settings> {
    initialSettings: Settings;
    RenderControls: ComponentType<{
        state: Settings;
        update(s: Partial<Settings>): void;
    }>;
    RenderContents: ComponentType<Settings & Size>;
    toolPadding?: number | string | Padding;
}
```

The `Tool` component itself handles the logic for sizing things to the screen and for updating the settings.

```
export const Tool = <Settings extends {}>({initialSettings, RenderControls, RenderContents, toolPadding = 0}: Props<Settings>) => {
    const [settings, update] = usePartialState<Settings>(initialSettings);
    const [ref, dimensions] = useDimensions();
    const {width = 0, height = 0, y = 0} = dimensions;
    const padding = padAmounts({width, toolPadding});
    const toolHeight = window.innerHeight - (Math.max(y, 0) + height + padding.top + padding.bottom);
    const toolWidth = width - (padding.left + padding.right);

    return (
        <div>
            <div ref={ref}>
                <RenderControls
                    state={settings}
                    update={update}
                />
            </div>
            <div style={{
                paddingLeft: padding.left,
                paddingRight: padding.right,
                paddingTop: padding.top,
                //don't include the bottom as a failsafe to prevent unnecessary scrolling
            }}>
                <RenderContents
                    {...settings}
                    width={toolWidth}
                    height={toolHeight}
                />
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}
```

When I create a `Tool`, I just pass in my two components and my `initialSettings`.  Sometimes I define an interface for the `Settings` and save the initial settings as a constant, other times I let the generic be inferred from the properties that I pass to `initialSettings`.  Here's one example of calling it:

```
export const HistogramTool = () => (
    <Tool
        initialSettings={{
            breakpoints: 6,
            group: randomGroup().name,
            channel: getChannel("hsl.l"),
        }}
        RenderControls={HistogramControls}
        RenderContents={GroupChannelHistogram}
        toolPadding={"10%"}
    />
);
```

Comment: This has given me some really good ideas, thanks so much, I'll be trying them out next week